# Displaying div, javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to display a hidden div in function after it will do some things but it doesn't work. Could you please help me with it? Here is what i tried to do:

@Edit
Ok, it's the code in short. After i click link calc there is a form, and after i click on input submit, there is and alert, and then it should display a div, but that's not working.

http://pastebin.com/XU58GhFv

Comment: The posted code works just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zr3cor4u/ if you want help, you have to show us exactly how it's not working ?

Comment: Maybe it's because of alert, my function is displaying an alert before, like:
alert("some words");
        var variable = document.getElementById("evolves-calculator");
        $(variable).css('display', 'block');
May it be the problem?

Comment: Post your whole code please, so we can identify the error. Dont post here on the comments, update your question

Comment: Ok, neverminds, it's not this, without and alert it's not working either. But what about this:
<input onclick="calculator()" type="submit" value="submit">
The function performs when i click on submit, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: You're probably missing a `document.ready` handler

Comment: I edited the code, yes that may be the problem with document.ready, im actually reading it on the google, my friend wrote me the code of first function and it is in jquery, which i don't, im just learning the javascript, so im trying to fix my code according to his code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the id directly in JQuery.

```
`$("#evolves-calculator").css('display', 'block');`
```